# Can I use OpenID in a "white-label" way for local logins?

Tags: authentication, openid

**The short version:** Can I use an OpenID (or other similar) provider behind the scenes to create "local accounts" on my web site?

**The details:** I'm working on a site that requires the user to log in. I plan to support logins via several OpenID providers. However, even though we technical people know that actual credentials are not shared with a relying party site, some users are nevertheless reluctant to use their third-party credentials in this way. That means that in actual practice, most sites that offer an OpenID login also offer the option to create a local account specific to that site.

But this puts me back in the situation of having to create the infrastructure to securely handle passwords, password resets, etc, etc, etc -- the very situation that OpenID tries to save me from.

It would be great if I could create an account on behalf of my users at some OpenID provider when they choose to create a local account on my site instead of signing in with an existing OpenID account. Then I would just store the same kind of data that I store for Google and Twitter accounts.

Are there providers that work in this way? Is this a dumb idea? Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe https://auth0.com/ would suit your needs.

They have integration with many social networks but also offer "local" user accounts. "Local" DB is stored either on their side or it is even possible to connect your own DB (but this starts at $99/month).

Comment: Thank you! That is indeed almost exactly what I need but it is quite expensive if you think you'll have a lot of logins each day. I've upvoted you but I'm going to keep this question open in case anyone has some less expensive ideas.